# How to put rabbit request into Confirm mode, not entire channel into Confirm mode

Tags: go, rabbitmq, amqp, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmq-channel

I just want Confirm mode for a single request, not to affect the entire channel (other requests made with that channel).

This bit of code modifies the channel:

```
/// Enable Confirm mode
if err := ch.Confirm(false); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error enabling Confirm mode: %s", err)
}

/// Create a confirmation channel
confirms := ch.NotifyPublish(make(chan amqp.Confirmation, 1))

/// publish the message
err := ch.PublishWithContext(
    toCtx,
    virl_const.RMQMainExchange,
    routingKey,
    false,
    false,
    amqp.Publishing{
        ContentType:  "application/json",
        Body:         v,
        DeliveryMode: amqp.Transient,
        Headers: map[string]interface{}{
            "x-vibe-type": 1,
        },
    },
)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error publishing message: %s", err)
}

// Wait for confirmation
select {
case confirmed := <-confirms:
    if confirmed.Ack {
        fmt.Println("Message confirmed by server")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Message not confirmed by server")
    }
case <-time.After(time.Second * 5):
    fmt.Println("Timed out waiting for confirmation")
}
```

but I want to just modify the one request. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Confirms are at the channel level. Why would you need a confirm on a single publish and not on all others? Alternatively, create a separate channel with confirm enabled for that single publish.

Comment: Yikes - so this channel is being used for more than one type of request. For one type of request, want a confirmation, for another type of request - no confirmation. So just create two different channels - yes of course, but that just puts the burden on me instead of having the library do the work, which of course is the point of using a library, etc etc.

Comment: Using the same channel to process two different kinds of publish is flawed to begin with.

Comment: Strangely conceited POV. How would you know that? I have a channel created for each logged in user (websocket session). So that channel is associated with the user session and ideally would be reused by that user until they disconnect, or other big event. The guidelines for RMQ channels are vague and my sentiment is that the design itself is flawed and poor.  If you are a contributor to RMQ and are simply being defensive, than please state so, because that's understandable...however see next comment -

Comment: I am not actually using the channel for different types of requests (although that should be no issue). I am just reusing a channel for multiple publish requests of the same kind. If that's not a good practice, (the practice of reusing a channel at all), aka using it for multiple publish requests, than that's a damnation of RMQ itself

Comment: Of course you have two different kinds of publish, that’s the premise of your question. Using the same channel for the same user might make sense but it shows its limitation in cases like the one you are describing right now. I’m not affiliated with RabbitMQ in any way. I’m just someone who uses it in production

Comment: ok, but no. I am simply calling the same function more than once - so I want to use the same channel for both calls, nothing more complicated than that. bemusing, I will inquire more later. thanks anyway.